# getElementByClass Split and then Display string + html

Tags: javascript, html, dom, innerhtml

this is my first ever question and im sure its clear that I am new to this but hungry to learn! Any help is very appreciated.

I have a page where I need to grab the text of a class and then split it, displaying the first part [0] as a string and the end of the string [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hubjU.png) as an .

the string / iframe is separated by ##.
an example is

`description description description ## <iframe>`

currently the page displays it all as one long string.

as far as I have got is the follow:

```
var musicPlayer = document.getElementsByClassName(".program-description-text");
var fields = musicPlayer.split('##');
var myVideoDescription = fields[0];
var embedLink = fields[1];
```

Im sure this is wrong but assuming its not i still dont know how to display the results and how to call this to go grab and split the class string.

Thank you to anyone who takes the time to read this.

Edit:
I guess im so new that I can not find the right description for what I would like to achieve so I have taken some screen shots and edited one to show what I would like the result to be.

[image: screen shot of the inspector window with the string I would like to split highlighted]
[image: edited image to show what I would like the]
[image: Screenshot of the input field with an example iframe- This iframe is shown is displayed as a text string on the site. this can not be changed so I want to do it on the "front end"]

Comment: `dont know how to display the results`, Well how do you want to display the result? In HTML? In console? etc?

Comment: Can you also show your `html`

Comment: Please, show your HTML.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is `.program-description-text`? What you want to do and where do you want to show the result? Provide your HTML.

Comment: Another thing to mention except the fact that we don't know where you want to display your code is that `getElementsByClassName` expects the class name without the dot in front so `program-description-text` instead of `.program-description-text`

Comment: I have updated question to include some images. I hope this is clearer for everyone

Answer (score -2):

musicPlayer will likely be an array. You should try to console.log the musicPlayer and see what it contains.

Comment: You should provide a solution and explain your idea, StackOverflow answers are not meant to work like chat boxes.